# How do I read images in their sequential order?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, imread

I have got images in a directory and  images/input set of filenames are : 
a1.jpg , a2.jpg , a3.jpg, ...a900.jpg

I want to read images based on the image names in sequential order and do some processing. But the problem it reads images randomly and not in order.

for fixing this problem I wrote the following program based on `natsorted`. However, it does not do the job correctly.

```
def load_images(path):
    image_list=[]
    images= glob.glob(path)
    images = natsorted(images)

    for index in range(len(images)):
        image= cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(images[index]),cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image_list.append(cv2.resize(image,(1920,1080)))

    return image_list
```

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem.
The [natsort](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) package is behaving correctly.

```
>>> from natsort import natsorted
>>> imgs = [f'a{i}' for i in range(12, 0, -1)]
>>> 
>>> sorted(imgs)
['a1', 'a10', 'a11', 'a12', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6', 'a7', 'a8', 'a9']
>>> 
>>> natsorted(imgs)
['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6', 'a7', 'a8', 'a9', 'a10', 'a11', 'a12']
>>> 
>>> imgs
['a12', 'a11', 'a10', 'a9', 'a8', 'a7', 'a6', 'a5', 'a4', 'a3', 'a2', 'a1']
```

Comment: If that is correct, so why I am getting some random images in between? what would be another way to sort them?

Comment: I showed you an example of the natsort package behaving correctly. You haven't shown us your input set of filenames, haven't shown us how to reproduce the error. You are not helping us help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: My input sets are "a1.jpg , a2.jpg , a3.jpg, ...a900.jpg" is it clear now?

Comment: You chose not to read the mcve guide. You need to show actual vs expected output. When I tried assigning `imgs = [f'a{i}.jpg' for i in range(900, 0, -1)]` I saw `pprint.pprint(natsorted(imgs))` do exactly what I'd expect, displaying in numeric order. I showed code, with output, that does the expected thing. If there is python behavior you were hoping random SO folks would go to the trouble of reproducing on their machines, you have not yet described how to produce or evaluate that behavior.